# How to count (unique) custom values for a metric in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Trying to figure out "how many users logged-in last month?" on my website using Google Analytics' web-interface (or API).

For each request, I'm sending user id's in a custom variable as the value:

```
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'user_id', '#{ current_user ? current_user.id : 0 }']);
```

**How can I get the number of unique user id's for all pageviews within a certain time-range?**

Comment: I guess I could create a table with 2 columns,"Custom Variable (Value 02)" and "Pageviews", and then just count the number of rows. But that's hacky, especially because it requires me to fetch all the rows from GA and then count them locally.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? You posted it back in 2012, but I have the same question. I don't want to count the total rows, i just want the count already totaled. How hard is it to get a sum of unique user IDs?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom segment[*] that includes only visitors with your custom var set. Apply the segment and the audience overview tab will display your desired numbers.

[*] Advanced segments->create custom  segment -> first dropdown to "include", second to "Custom Variable 2", third "Exactly matching" and the textfield gets the value for logged-in visitors

Comment: The steps you suggest yield a report containing only requests with user id's. However, it doesn't appear to show the number of unique user id's anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not possible in Google Analytics.
But you can do this in Google Data Studio. There you can create Dashboards for Google Analytics and create a new calculated field, like: COUNT(User ID)